# Jenkins build failure Killed npm start

Tags: jenkins, github, npm, protractor

I have problem with starting my (angular) project on Jenkins. I wrote this code into execute shell and  pulled code from github :

**pwd 

npm start &

sleep 250

protractor config/browserstack.conf.js**

and got this FAILURE:

**Killed                  npm start

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE**

Some time building was successful but protractor command starts in the middle of build process and all test crashed.

I tried to add this code into execute shell 
**set +e

or

/bin/sh +xe**

but still not working.

Everything worked fine until last 3-4 days !

Comment: I have a couple of questions: #1 Because you are starting up a Angular website on port 4200 (probably), will you only have one executor for your Jenkins job or could you have ports being used? #2 Is there additional logs that happen before the error?

Comment: I'm starting an app on port 3000 , sometimes when that port is in use ( I had that error few times ) I killed that process on port 3000 with fuser -k 3000/tcp and started all over again.

Comment: See the above comment on adding more logs and stack traces.